# Are smaller redis keys more efficient

Tags: redis

I am working on implementing a page cache using Redis. It works, but i am currently using the url as the Redis key. Hashing will of course cost me CPU time, but it will make the key smaller and less complicated. Will smaller, hashed redis keys outperform a key that is based off a page url?

Comment: If it would, which I doubt, hashing will cost all benefits and more

Comment: I prefer to hash the keys. With a fast hash algorithm, such as Murmurhash, it doesn't cost too much. The benefit of hashing, is you can have a smaller data set in memory, especially when the the original key is very large.